# Is it ok to submit a build to the app store for testing when a previous build is waiting for review?

Tags: ios, app-store, testflight

I recently submitted an app for review, and it's currently in "Waiting for Review" status.

I'd like to submit a new build and enable it for testing in TestFlight. When I set enable testing on for the new build, the store shows the message:

```
"are you sure you want to start testing 1.xx.20?  Testing for all builds of 1.xx.19 will stop, and you will send an update to your existing testers"
```

I don't care about testing the previous version, but I don't want to disrupt the review process. Is it ok to go ahead and enable testing for the new build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation implies the answer is yes:

> When the app becomes Ready for Sale in the App Store, testing
>   automatically stops on earlier builds, and you will be unable to view
>   or test them...If you want to resume testing of an earlier build, **you can upload it as a new build associated with a new prerelease version**.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/BetaTestingTheApp.html

Answer (score 3):

I do that all the time. Submit a new build for test flight while a previous build is waiting for the full review, never had any troubles.