# Is it possible to upload new build for testflight review while a build is already approved for testing?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I might not be the first one to ask this question but mine is slightly different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27234056/will-submitting-a-build-for-testflight-beta-testing-stop-the-final-review-test-f) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31123881/is-it-ok-to-submit-a-build-to-the-app-store-for-testing-when-a-previous-build-is)

I uploaded a build for testflight review and it got approved. But now I have an improved version. I am aware that I can upload this updated version to itunesconnect.

The question is -

1. How long it may take to get approval for my latest build?
2. In case the latest build is still waiting for review, can I still continue testing (external testers) with my already approved version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. How long it may take to get approval for my latest build?

- It will be approved *immediately*. 
  Once a Beta build is approved for testing, successive builds get approved immediately. In fact, at my firm, after submitting a build to the App Store, we just bump the build version & submit the app for Beta Testing to avoid Beta Review time to delay our testing.
  All our Beta builds after the initial one have been approved immediately.

> 2. In case the latest build is still waiting for review, can I still continue testing (external testers) with my already approved version?

- Yes, *but doesn't matters coz of above^*

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to question 1 :**

It depends, how long did it take for your last build ? Did you change a lot of code ? It may vary between 2 to 10 days (approximately).

**Answer to question 2 :**

Of course you can, when you will want to test your lastest build, you will be asked to remove from testing the current build. This is implemented in a way that you can be waiting for review on your lastest build but still test a recent build of your application.

If you have any other question about TestFlight/Release feel free to ask but keep in mind that a lot of similar questions had already been asked/answered.

Hope it helped.